# npm5 missing build script

Tags: node.js, npm

Using NPM 5, run npm test:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "babel src -d dist",
    "test": "npm run build; mocha --require 'babel-polyfill' --compilers js:babel-register './tests/**/*.spec.js'"
  },
```

I get this error:

```
npm ERR! missing script: build;
```

Using NPM 2 without any problem

If I replace npm run build; => babel src -d dist, I got this error:

```
mocha doesn't exist. './tests/**/*.spec.js' doesn't exist
```

but mocha is installed and tests folder exixts.

Comment: What command are you running exactly?

Comment: I am running npm test

Comment: Running npm run build is sucessful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tried to check your error, and created this code:

```
{
 ...
 "scripts": {
   "build": "echo 'building'",
   "test": "npm run build && echo 'testing'"
 },
...
}
```

then I simply ran:

```
npm test
```

and this was my output:

```
building
testing
```

npm - 5.0.3

So try maybe replacing ";" with "&&" in npm test